# How to delete commas from first and last line of csv file?

Tags: bash, shell

My csv file is exported like this:

```
+++ Host - Begin +++,,

Name,Description

test1,abc2

test2, abd3

+++ Host - End +++,,
```

What i need to do to get it like this above?

```
 +++ Host - Begin +++

Name,Description

test1,abc2

test2, abd3

+++ Host - End +++
```

Comment: remove the two commas.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [line addressing](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Numeric-Addresses) in `sed` combined with the [substitution command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) will remove all commas from the first (`1`) and the last (`$`) line:

```
sed '1s/,//g; $s/,//g' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat test_file
+++ Host - Begin +++,,
Name,Description
test1,abc2
test2, abd3
+++ Host - End +++,,
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ sed -i -e '1s/,//g; $s/,//g;' test_file
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $ cat test_file
+++ Host - Begin +++
Name,Description
test1,abc2
test2, abd3
+++ Host - End +++
neech@nicolaw.uk:~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is yet another solution using `sed` command.

```
sed 's/[,]*$//' infile
```